# How can I add String JList element from another JPanel/JFrame/etc?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jlist, swingworker

I know how to actually add the element to the JList itself, but I am unsure how to make my Event Log (which uses the JList along with a DefaultListModel) update as the updates actually occur. It seems as though my application freezes up then all entries are shown when it's over. Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 100% sure that you've got a Swing concurrency issue where you're tying up the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT with a long-running process. The problem is that the Swing even thread is responsible for performing all Swing drawing and user interactions. If it is tied up with some long running process such as file or database input or output, then it can't perform its responsibilities, and the whole GUI becomes frozen. The solution is to use a background thread such as a SwingWorker, so that the long-running process doesn't tie up the EDT, but taking care to update Swing components such as the JList or its model *on* the EDT.

Please check out the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details on the problem and its solution.

Comment: were you a gunslinger in your past life? ;] +1

Comment: I have multithreading in my program. It's doing a file conversion on each thread. If I wanted updates to the Log when each thread was complete, would I need to have as many SwingWorkers as Threads?

Comment: @BackpackOnHead: I'm not sure. It is not an absolute requirement that you use a SwingWorker, but it does offer some convenience methods and structure for doing background processing in Swing. It is necessary for you to do your processing in a background thread though, and you may wish to use a thread pool of some sort.

Comment: The thing is, I won't always have the same output when a background task is "done". I guess I could store the message in a String though... Could I have, say, 8 SwingWorker's each running in it's own Thread without it freezing the GUI?

Comment: @BackpackOnHead: I believe so, but again, you'd likely want to pool your threads in some way. Best to make a test program and try these things out.

Comment: Works. I have either a success posted to the log or an error. They are put in a string and when done() is called, it outputs to the log. This works amazingly and is very simple. I had issues like this in the past and thought it was much more complicated. Thanks, a lot!